# When changing the background width it's also changing the container position

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

What I am doing is, I have two background images and each image with a respective red box. The red box is an inside bootstrap container with position absolute. The first red box is on the right side and the second red box is on the left side.

Till there is no issue.

Now I
have to change the width of the background image because I have to give
left space on the first image and right space on the second image.

But If you notice if I give the space then it's changing the position of the container.
I don't want to change the position of the container.

When there is no space

[image]

Please check the below image. When there is a space

[image]

```css
.bodywrapper {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.bannerBg {
  height: 350px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 92%;
}

.wrapperOne {
  background-image: url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(45).jpg');
}

.wrapperTwo {
  background-image: url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(46).jpg');
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 220px;
  width: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0
}

.rightside {
  right: 0;
}

.leftside {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bodywrapper">

  <div class="wrapperOne bannerBg ml-auto">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box rightside"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapperTwo bannerBg mr-auto">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box leftside"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

v>

I need to know that is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't produces the results like 2 images that you took so I tweaked it a little bit.

```css
.bodywrapper {
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: right;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bannerBg {
  height: 350px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapperOne {
  background-image: url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(45).jpg');
  text-align: center;
  background-size: 70% 100%;
  background-position: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapperTwo {
  background-image: url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(46).jpg');
  text-align: center;
  background-size: 70% 100%;
  background-position: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 220px;
  width: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0
}

.rightside {
  right: 0;
}

.leftside {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="bodywrapper">

    <div class="wrapperOne bannerBg ml-auto">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="box rightside"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapperTwo bannerBg mr-auto">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="box leftside"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The main part is adding the below code to 2 `wrapper`

```
text-align: center;
background-size: 70% 100%;
background-position: right; //in wrapper one and  left in wrapper two
display: inline-block;
```

The idea is reducing the width of the wrapper's image, not the wrapper itself, so your container position doesn't change.

Comment: Give me some time to check.